# what value we can replace for NaN in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I used  GLCM techniques to feature extract from mamo images and then I used naive bayes classification to classify,

why the output column Included NaN?

What value can we replace NaN, when we have 1 output matrix from naive bayes classification (1 column Included 0,1,NaN)?

code:

```
Train_Test();

nb = NaiveBayes.fit(Ytrain, Traininglabel);

y = nb.predict(Ytest);

confusionmat(Testinglabel,y);
```

output:

```
y=
[NaN
NaN
NaN
0
0
0
NaN
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0]
```

Comment: Usually something went wrong somewhere in your code when you get NaN values! You should first investigate how they got there in the first place and if you can fix the problem if there is any.

Comment: Post the values of your training data/labels or check if there are any NaN's in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When observations in your training data contain NaN values, by default `NaiveBayes.predict` will not classify them into any class, returning NaN as the predicted value.

By using the `HandleMissing` option to `predict`, you can change this behaviour. By default it's set to `off`, but if you set it to `on` it predicts using only variables with non-NaN values, and shouldn't return NaN as a prediction (unless *all* the variables are NaN).

Try

```
y = nb.predict(Ytest, 'HandleMissing', 'on');
```